# (Java/netty) What's the easiest way to send and receive variable-size objects with Netty?

Tags: java, object, networking, netty

So, I have a `Message` class, which contains all the information I want to send. However, its contents can vary wildly.

What's the easiest way to send and receive (specially the decode/reassembly part) such kind of objects through a Netty channel? (using Netty 3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use a 4-byte length prefix.  We use a subclass of the [OneToOneEncoder](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/codec/oneone/OneToOneEncoder.html) on the sending side and a subclass of the [LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/codec/frame/LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.html) on the receiver side.

Write message:

```
    private static final byte[] LENGTH_PLACEHOLDER = new byte[4];

    ChannelBufferOutputStream bout =
        new ChannelBufferOutputStream(dynamicBuffer(512, ctx.getChannel().getConfig().getBufferFactory()));
    bout.write(LENGTH_PLACEHOLDER);

    // write message contents here ...

    ChannelBuffer encoded = bout.buffer();
    encoded.setInt(0, encoded.writerIndex() - 4);
    return encoded;
```

Constructor params for LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder:

```
private static final int MAX_OBJECT_SIZE = 1 << 21;

public MyDecoder() 
{
    super(MAX_OBJECT_SIZE, 0, 4, 0, 4);
}
```

Read message:

```
    ChannelBuffer frame = (ChannelBuffer) super.decode(ctx, channel, buffer);
    if (frame == null) {
        return null;
    }

    ChannelBufferInputStream data = new ChannelBufferInputStream(frame);

    // read message here ...
```

Comment: So, there is no way the Netty library will prepend this length value when I send an object? (and, when receiving, checking it?)

Comment: This solution seems to be very close to what I want... could you provide some code snippets showing how exactly to write it?

Comment: @EduardoBezerra - you prepend it when you write in the encoder, and the frame based decoder will auto-magically read it and ensure that it has all the data before attempting decoding.

Answer (score 2):

The `ReplayingDecoder` is probably what you're looking for:

http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.1/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/codec/replay/ReplayingDecoder.html

Rather than throwing an error if there isn't enough data, this will silently fail and retry `decode()` until all the data is available.

Here's a tutorial showing this in action:

http://biasedbit.com/netty-tutorial-replaying-decoder/

Comment: I've seen this tutorial, but it seemed a bit convoluted, with too much code... I wonder if there isn't a shorter, more elegant way to do the same... For one thing, I believe the length attribute would be enough (the others could be inside the message object).